# Is the question "Can I borrow (person) for a while?" correct usage of English?

Tags: grammaticality, semantics, acceptability

Supposing the person is in a classroom, and a teacher is present. If someone from outside the classroom asks the teacher "Can I borrow this person?", would it be correct usage of English? Can you borrow people?

Comment: **Grammatically** it's fine: there's a subject, a verb and an object. Presumably you are not asking about the grammar, but rather the meaning. I've retagged the question.

Comment: Thank you for retagging. Does the question make sense? A lot of people gave me weird looks when I asked the question.

Comment: Your profile mentions India. I would say it's perfectly normal in the UK, but maybe it isn't in India (if that's where you are asking from). Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include your last comment, and add a tag for the particular form of English you're asking about. There are tags like [american-english] [indian-english] and the like.

Comment: This is a fairly common informal idiomatic usage in business office environments in the US.

Comment: It's also a fairly common/idiomatic usage in say a classroom or work situation in the UK. I've again retagged as I believe that questions about acceptability need tagging as such. The issue is not grammaticality (whether it works) but register (in which situations it works). It's rather tongue-in-cheek; not even Tommy Cooper would have risked "Could I just borrow the Queen for a couple of minutes?" So, although it's grammatically fine to use a named person as the DO referent (though in no dictionary I've looked in), judiciousness is vital.

Comment: You may not be aware of our sister site, SE English Language Learners. I strongly suggest that this sort of question may fit there, rather than on "a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". And please do us the courtesy of finishing reading the [Tour] where the scope of this site is explained.

Comment: Sticklers (ike elementary teachers) may insist that you should say "**May** I borrow...", asking for pemission to do it; and  not "**Can** I borrow...", asking if you have the ability to do it.

Comment: In the same way that we don't own other people, neither do we borrow or loan them.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase itself means,

> I need this person to come with me and they will return shortly.

and is considered valid English in most parts of the US as well as UK in work and school environments.

The goal of anything we say is to get the message across to the people around us which isn't really the case in India when you say that phrase. I have used the phrase in that exact scenario and everyone laughed as they thought it was incorrect English.

So, while it is correct English in the sense that it's used, when used with people who aren't used to that phrase, it will come off as bad or incorrect English and the person may not even understand your intentions—which defeats the entire purpose of saying it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting point about word semantics.

Consider the situation where person A is in an activity with person B (let's say a meeting or a class led by B), and person C wants to have person A leave the meeting temporarily to attend to something else quickly and then return.

Then it is a common thing for person C to say:

> Can I borrow A for a moment?

Another way of saying this is

> Can I have A attend this other thing with me for a moment?

The word 'borrow' captures all of that. You borrow a thing from one person  to use it and then return it later.

But of course you can see now with the meaning of 'borrow' made explicit, it sounds inappropriate. After all, people are not things and you don't use people, those are restrictions on words normally associated with individuals.

But that's just how it feels to use 'Can I borrow a person?'. It sounds a little funny (both strange and humorous) to treat a person like an object, but it gets across the idea that they will be gone only for a little while and return, all in one word.

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense and it's commonly used in a work/study setting, so the only reason people may have been taken aback by it is that they just didn't expect it in the context it was used? Some detail on when and how it was used would help, but, purely in grammatical terms, it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Borrow is a good word for this situation.  It means you need that person for something and implies that it will not be a long time and that you will bring them back when you are done.

It fills in a lot of questions like:

"Do you need them for the rest of the day?"

"Do **I** need to come get them later?"